# What is the nature of Aristotle's differentia?

Tags: logic, aristotle

I'm reading (Cat, 3a21):

> This is not, however, peculiar to substance: The differentia also is **not in a subject**. For footed and two footed are **said of** man as a subject but are not in a subject ...

So, from what I understand, differentia is a genera or a species. Then, would this imply that a substance has several species and genera?

For example, if the individual man is white, then he would have animal as genera but also white as differentia which, as I understand will also be a genera.

Also, is differentia a thing? It seemed to me that it wasn't but then if it is a genera I suppose it must be under A's framework.

Comment: It must be a *property*; see [Genus–differentia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93differentia_definition). See also [Difefrentia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentia).

Comment: See [Species, Genus, and Differentia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/?PHPSESSID=2cf18c476d4ef64b4ca15ba03d618211#SpeGenDif) : "Since a definition defines an essence, only what has an essence can be defined. In general, however, it is not individuals but rather speciesthat have essences. A species is defined by giving its genus and its differentia: the genus is the kind under which the species falls, and the differentia tells what characterizes the species within that genus. As an example, human might be defined as animal (genus) having the capacity to reason (differentia)."

Comment: And see : Edgar Herbert Granger, [Aristotle on Genus and Differentia](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/226965), JouHistPhil (1984).

Comment: Ok, great I'll read them. Also, can you check again the question? I changed it a lot. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: "... the genus is the kind under which the species falls, and the differentia tells what characterizes the species within that genus." Is the differentia said of the subject or said in the subject? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Differentia is not a thing, it is a property of a thing, or, as Aristotelians called it, an attribute, an essential quality. As in "man is a thinking animal" the "thinking" would be the differentia, an attribute distinguishing men from other animals.

Comment: As far as I understand from reading J.K Ackrill commentaries on the categories, when A is speaking of categories he is thinking of things, not just of words or linguistic figures. In this sense, even though he calls them qualities he is indeed thinking of actual things. But, even so, if the differential is an essential part of a primary substance definition, then it would be substancial as well, and taking on his later account according to Herbert Granger, it would be a genera, a kind, not just merely a caracteristic as he speaks at first in his categories. @Conifold

Comment: Aristotle distinguishes form and matter, and forms are not actual things. Essence belongs to the form, so it is not the way primary substances, "things", are. Aristotle is a realist about qualities (universals), but he is a hylomorphist, not a Platonist.

Answer (score 3):

*Long comment*

There are several places where A discuss the *species, genera* and *differentia* issue: *Topics*, **Book IV**, *Cat,5* and *Meta*, **Book VII (Z)**.

They are related to *essence* (and *substance*), *definitions* and the "process" of *division*.

*Animal rational* is obtained with the genera *animal* by division : some animals are *rational*, while some are not.

Thus, the *species* "animal rational" is obtained from the genera *animal* "adding" the differentia *rational*.

Comment: An. Post. II 13, 96a32 & 96b15 are also relevant but of course you have indicated the main texts and did not say you were offering a complete enumeration. Given yours, there is no need for any other answer. Best : GT

Comment: From what understood from Edgar Herbert Granger, Aristotle on Genus and Differentia, He argues that this account that the differential is just a characteristic added to a kind is probably prior in him and that later on he considered the differential to have even the same level of importance to define a substance as the genera and that was probably also of the same kind of the genera. From what I see of your answer it seems to me that you think that the first account is the right one. Do you disagree with Herbert Granger? @MauroALLEGRANZA